# Strange Server Problems

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server

I'm having some server issues, hopefully someone might have some insight.

There is one server in my workplace which is set up strangely and I don't understand it. Every machine can ping/access/share with every other machine on the network except this one server. It is inaccessible except for an online website it hosts which can be found at (say):

help.company.com/webapp

However pinging help.company.com gets no response although the IP is resolved to (say) 192.168.9.108.

To access this server you have to Remote Desktop onto a different server (say: helpdepartment) and from that machine you can Remote Desktop to help.company.com (or just "help" which seems to be sufficient). So basically you have to go through 2 layers of Remote Desktop. From this machine other machines on the network are unreachable and it appears that it is the only computer on the network. I don't have much experience with networks so this confuses me (are they bridged or something?).

EDIT: Just realised that the weird server hosts a public website. Must be why it's segregated from the rest of the network. Security?

Anyway my problem is that I need to write an application which can connect to a MS SQL Server which is running on the weird "help" machine (the same database the internal website accesses - it's a bug tracking application). However any attempts at connecting are "refused". But it's refused not "host unknown" so there is definitely *some* interaction. Clearly this problem is linked with the strange setup described above (for all I know it's standard practice - I'm ignorant).

The firewall on the "help" machine is disabled. The ports are all configured to 1433 (default) on the MS SQL Server. I've been through about a million articles with various different fixes but nothing helped. The servers run Windows Server 2003 by the way.

So, anyone have any insight?

Thanks in advance; this has been driving me crazy.
Carl

Comment: Ask the person that set it up this way, this is not really a standardish setup.

Comment: So it's not normal then. Yeah I should probably contact somebody internal if that's the case.

Comment: Sounds like your network has been carved up into vlans (or possibly just subnets) with extremely limited connectivity between them -- You'll need to find the person responsible for your network architecture/firewalls and ask them to give you a diagram...

Comment: It sounds to me like the SCW has been run on that server. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757109(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is a "DMZ" because it faces out onto the Internet. That's why I couldn't connect to it easily.

The solution was to use a different machine with a copy of the database I needed.